# Alternative for psutil for ARM processors (raspberry pi) and python3

Tags: monitoring, raspberry-pi, python3

As I am unable to install psutil to work on raspberry pi on python3, I am looking for any alternative (or a proper way to install it).

What I want is to be able to see what's the status of the computer in terms of CPU and RAM available, so that if that's the case I can "sleep" the script until the computer relaxes, in order to avoid that the script just finishes without any apparent reason.

Any idea?

Comment: which distribution are you using on your raspberry pi?

Comment: raspbian (updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it appears there's no alternative, I will follow this strategy
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=

Comment: The link has gone stale. That's why you are supposed to post answers instead of just links. The Wayback machine may help.